# When i init taiilwind everytime appearance this errorr

Tags: node.js, npm

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Users\admin\Desktop\anugular-tutor\store\store
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: What version of node and what version of npm are you using?

Comment: node 16.17.1   npm & npx 8.19.2